# Inheritance / Calling function from object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, inheritance, function-calls

## Hello!

I am rather new to Javascript. I am better in Java so I get confused in many things about Javascript. I've created **class** **Clovek** witch has some variables and functions. Later I've created **array Lide** witch has MAX (100) objects of **Clovek** in it. So when I called later to call function **vypis** I got only TypeError .. blah blah is not a function. But when i wrote ** console.trace(lide[1])** for example it wrote that is an instance of Clovek. I am confused..

### Code here:

```
function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for( var i=0; i < 8; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

var odstavec = document.getElementById("test");

function Clovek(vek, pohlavi, jmeno) {
    this.vek = vek;
    this.pohlavi = pohlavi;
    this.jmeno = jmeno;
}

Clovek.prototype.vypis = function() {
    //console.log(this.vek+" "+this.pohlavi+" "+this.jmeno);
    //odstavec.innerHTML = this.vek+" "+this.pohlavi+" "+this.jmeno;
    return this.vek+" "+this.pohlavi+" "+this.jmeno;
};


var MAX = 100; // Maximální počet 

var lide = [MAX];

for( var i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    _tempclovek = new Clovek(i,"muz",makeid());
    lide.push(_tempclovek);
    console.log(_tempclovek.vypis());
};

var table = document.createElement("table");
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

for (var i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    _tempclovek = lide[i];
    console.trace(_tempclovek.vypis());
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(_tempclovek); 

    cell.appendChild(cellText);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
};


var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
table.appendChild(tbody);
body.appendChild(table);
table.setAttribute("border", "2");
```

#### EDIT - That code lies inside HTML document im `<script>` tag

Comment: Use `var lide = [];` instead of `var lide = [MAX];`. Javascript does not give a native way to limit the number of elements in an array. `[MAX]` just gives you an array with one element in it: the number `MAX` or `100` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with length using `new Array(MAX)`.
This will create an array of `100` null values. If you use push, it will append it to array, so use `lide[i]` instead.

#### Code

```js
function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

var odstavec = document.getElementById("test");

function Clovek(vek, pohlavi, jmeno) {
    this.vek = vek;
    this.pohlavi = pohlavi;
    this.jmeno = jmeno;
}

Clovek.prototype.vypis = function () {
    //console.log(this.vek+" "+this.pohlavi+" "+this.jmeno);
    //odstavec.innerHTML = this.vek+" "+this.pohlavi+" "+this.jmeno;
    return this.vek + " " + this.pohlavi + " " + this.jmeno;
};

var MAX = 100; // Maximální počet 
var lide = new Array(MAX);

for (var i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    var _tempclovek = new Clovek(i, "muz", makeid());
    lide[i] = _tempclovek;
    //console.log(_tempclovek.vypis());
};


var table = document.createElement("table");
var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

for (var i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    var _tempclovek = lide[i];
    console.log("Type Of: " ,typeof(lide[i]))
    console.log(lide)
    console.trace(_tempclovek.vypis());
    var cellText = document.createTextNode(_tempclovek.vypis()); 

    cell.appendChild(cellText);
    row.appendChild(cell);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
};


var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
table.appendChild(tbody);
body.appendChild(table);
table.setAttribute("border", "2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over `lide` starting at element 0, which is the integer 100 and not an instance of `Clovek`.

Answer (score 1):

**1. Array definiton**
Use `var lide = [];` instead of `var lide = [MAX];`. Javascript does not give a native way to limit the number of elements in an array. `[MAX]` just gives you an array with one element in it: the number `MAX`, or 100 in this case.

**2. Variable scope**
In your for loops, use the keyword `var` when defining the variable `_tempclovek` so that it uses `_tempclovek` in local scope rather than global scope. If you don't use `var` when defining a variable in js, it creates a global variable, which can lead to unexpected results.

**3. Objects as strings**
Your call to `createTextNode()` should be calling the `vypis()` function on your `Clovek` object. Otherwise you will get the default string value for your object, which is `[object Object]` in js.

http://jsfiddle.net/pcbpa9p5/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will do it your way. Thanks !